# $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\left(2xy-9x^2+\left(2y+x^2+1\right)\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\left(2xy-9x^2+\left(2y+x^2+1\right)\right)$$

I am trying to implicitly solve this equation, but I barely know anything about Calculus.

So far I have tried to separate into $2xy-9x^2$, and solve the partial derivative by $x$.

Then I tried solving $2y+x^2+1$, and solve the partial derivative by $y$.

Then I added both partial derivatives, and have to substitute it into the very top implicit function.

Then according Paul Online Notes on exact differential functions, it said to substitute this into the entire function from the very top.

Other than that I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Good for you! Here are some things to keep in mind: 1) Only seperable differential equations are in the AP cirriculum, 2) This is not a site to do all of your work, 3) Please put in more effort if you want positive attention.

Comment: like what? Was I not specific.

Comment: You should show us what steps you have tried.

Comment: "Only can solve polynomial explicit functions!" What does this mean? What methods have you been exposed to so far to solve differential equations? You don't get to a question like that in DE without ever seeing one solved before.

Comment: Good job providing some context. Seems strange $-9x^2$ and $x^2$ exist alongside each other without being simplified - why would they occur like that? (Not a rhetorical question, I really don't know.)

Comment: I replied late, I'm trying to solve the integral of this entire function. I have skipped to this because I wanted to find the whole integral of this function. sorry

Comment: Well at least I tried asking it clearly. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an integrating factor. Multiply the equation by $z$, a yet to be determined function of $x$,

$$z\frac{dy}{dx}=2(x+1)zy +z(1-8x^2)$$

Now we want to have

$$\frac{d(zy)}{dx}=z\frac{dy}{dx}-2(x+1)zy$$ 
 and this means that 
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=-2(x+1)z$$ from which we see by inspection or separation of variables that $z=e^{-(x+1)^2}$

Thus we have

$$\frac{d(zy)}{dx}= (1-8x^2)e^{-(x+1)^2}$$

So

$$y=e^{(x+1)^2}\left(\int (1-8x^2)e^{-(x+1)^2}dx +C\right)$$

Now of course the integral cannot be evaluated in terms or elementary functions, so either I made a mistake (highly likely) or the question is miscopied or that is as far as one can go.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for it to be defined implicitly.

Comment: What you mean ? A functional relation between $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: yes, thanks, is it possible?

Comment: where did the comments go! I meant to solve as a relation. Thank you!

Comment: I dont see how. I have reduced it to the problem $y^{\prime}=(1-8x^2)e^{-(x+1)^2}$, how is one supposed to get a functional relation ? Usually integrating factors lead to functional relations. Are you sure the problem is correct ?

Comment: You could separate the whole relation into two terms, and then substitute into the relation, and solve by 0. Or you can look at Paul's online notes on "exact differential equations". I couldn't understand the notes.

Comment: Sorry I just dont know what more can be done here, I have follows the procedure found on the notes.

Comment: If you can edit it, thanks, don't want to make your night busier!

Answer (score 1):

As Rene Schipperus rigorously showed, the solution of the differential equation is  $$y=e^{(x+1)^2}\left(\int (1-8x^2)e^{-(x+1)^2}dx +C\right)$$ and, since $$1-8x^2 =-7+16(x+1)-8(x+1)^2$$ you could establish that $$\int (1-8x^2)e^{-(x+1)^2}dx=4 e^{-(x+1)^2} (x-1)-\frac{11}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(x+1)$$ After simplification $$y=4 x-4+ C e^{(x+1)^2}-\frac{11}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{(x+1)^2} \text{erf}(x+1)$$ which cannot be expressed in a simpler form as Rene Schipperus already wrote.